# Is it possible in Flutter to reuse TextEditingController?

Tags: flutter, textfield

In my application, there is a lot of TextFields like more than 50.

```
class BoxFieldItem extends StatelessWidget {
  BuildContext context;

  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  TextEditingController textControler;


  BoxFieldItem(this.title,this.subtitle,){
    textControler=new TextEditingController();

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextField(
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        controller: textControler,
    /*    onChanged: (String e) {

        },*/
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.lightBlue[40],
            filled: true,

            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),

            labelText: title,
            hintText: subtitle,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
            border:
            OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have this Widget class ,trouble is when i use it like:   BoxFieldItem('Title','sub'), text entered disapiar if i scroll or click next?
What im doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your implementation. I would create a `widget` that wrap the `TextField` and its `controller` then in your page you just need use the created widget and provide different configurations via constructor.

To listen for changes in the `TextField` you can just provide a callback to be used in your page.

Comment: I edited question, is there any way to use the same TextEditingController for different fields?